# No intellisense with direct-initialization syntax in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

When I type

```
Widget w = Widget(
```

intellisense automatically give a popup where I can navigate through the available constructors. Where as if I type

```
Widget w(
```

I get no such popup. Nor does the shortcut(Ctrl+Shift+Space) bring it up. I tried resetting my settings but it didn't help. Anyone know if this behavior is intended or if it's fixable?

Comment: Assuming this is not a problem with ambiguous statement but IntelliSense failing. Try doing _Project_ -> _Rescan Solution_ and if that doesn't work, deleting `<SolutionName>.sdf` file so it gets rebuilt next time you open your solution (might take a while). That said, IntelliSense sometimes just gets lost and refuses to work properly with big projects especially if they use complex template wizardry and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Widget w(...` could be the start of different things. e.g. the definition of an object named w (which seems to be what you want), but also a declaration of a function called `w`, returning a `Widget`. That might be a reason for intellisense to refuse to work.

For C++11 (which is supported by VS2013 IIRC) you could try uniform initialization as well:

```
Widget w{...
```

or even the new "auto" style proposed by Herb Sutter and others:

```
auto w = Widget{...
```

Comment: Isn't `auto w = Widget{...}` the same as `Widget w = Widget(...)`, or have I missed something?

Comment: It is the same as `Widget w = Widget{...}`, and that is the same as `Widget w = Widget(...)` unless there is an `initializer_list` ctor available in `Widget`. And `Widget w(...` is mostly the same as `Widget w = Widget(...)` (or the latter with `auto` and/or both with `{}`), unless the move- and/or copy-ctor of `Widget` is inaccessible. The ctor needs to be accessible but usually won't be called in copy-initialization.

Comment: Of course. And great suggestion about the new style. That's definitely on the to do list.